# How do you uninstall AVG free?

Tags: internet

It is hard to uninstall AVG free, I need to install other antivirus software.

Comment: What's so hard ? What problems/errors are you encountering ?

Comment: AVG is sort if like a mini-virus in that it doesn't like to be uninstalled.  @christine2008, just follow @RedGrittyBrick's steps, and delete the files from your Program Files directory.

Answer (score 2):

From the `Start` icon, select `Control-Panel`, `Add or Remove Programs`, `AVG`, `Remove`.